# SQL SERVER - Date conversion failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, union

I have a table in which `AccessDate` column is of type `datetime`.
And I am trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT 'AccessDate' UNION ALL SELECT AccessDate FROM table_name
```

I am trying to insert the header of the table "AccessDate" into the result of the query.
And this error shows up after executing:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: columns have to be of the same datatype when using `union`. one is char and the other is datetime in your example.

Comment: So casting AccessDate to VARCHAR will keep the format used by datetime?

Comment: security -> logins->youruser   right click - properties and check default language. 

Because if you are using another language, it  gives this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not surprising.  You appear to want a date in a column where there is already a character.  You need to convert the date to a string:

```
SELECT 'AccessDate' UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), AccessDate, 121)
FROM table_name;
```

You can use whatever format you like.  I prefer YYYY-MM-DD.